# jQuery - select dropdown - focusout gets fired before select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list which is populated using auto complete. However, the focusout gets fired BEFORE the select of the auto complete does.

```
        $('#licenceNumber').autocomplete({
        select: function (event, ui) {
         console.log(' I am SUPPOSED to get fired first ;(')
        }
    });

    $('#licenceNumber').focusout(function () {
        console.log(' I get fired first')

    });
```

Any tips on how to fix this issue?

Comment: can you show more of your code? i am too lazy to build a working autocomplete-script now, to be honest.

Comment: Ya bud, hold up would need to change a lot of stuff cuz need to remove anything related to my work :P I'll try the answer posted and if it doesn't work, I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```
$('#licenceNumber').autocomplete({
     select: function (event, ui) {
          console.log(' I am SUPPOSED to get fired first');
     }
}).focusout(function () {
    console.log(' I get fired first');
});
```